# Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1 when deploying my NextJS site to Vercel. Any help welcome

Tags: next.js, vercel

I am trying to make a deploy my NextJS site to Vercel.

And I'm receiving the below errors that I can't seem to resolve.

Below is the Build Log:

Any help is very welcome. Thank you in advance.

```
[17:30:42.222] Cloning github.com/MoikeCheck/portfolio (Branch: main, Commit: 3f5806a)
[17:30:42.835] Cloning completed: 611.953ms
[17:30:43.283] Installing build runtime...
[17:30:46.702] Build runtime installed: 3.419s
[17:30:48.243] Looking up build cache...
[17:30:52.069] Build cache downloaded [51.60 MB]: 3402.218ms
[17:30:52.360] Installing dependencies...
[17:30:52.683] yarn install v1.22.17
[17:30:52.778] warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
[17:30:52.785] [1/4] Resolving packages...
[17:30:53.545] [2/4] Fetching packages...
[17:31:16.236] [3/4] Linking dependencies...
[17:31:16.237] warning " > @chakra-ui/icons@1.1.7" has unmet peer dependency "@chakra-ui/system@>=1.0.0".
[17:31:16.238] warning "@chakra-ui/icons > @chakra-ui/icon@2.0.5" has unmet peer dependency "@chakra-ui/system@>=1.0.0".
[17:31:16.248] warning "@chakra-ui/react > @chakra-ui/modal > react-remove-scroll@2.4.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0".
[17:31:16.248] warning "@chakra-ui/react > @chakra-ui/toast > @reach/alert@0.13.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.8.0 || 17.x".
[17:31:16.249] warning "@chakra-ui/react > @chakra-ui/toast > @reach/alert@0.13.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0 || 17.x".
[17:31:16.249] warning "@chakra-ui/react > @chakra-ui/modal > @chakra-ui/focus-lock > react-focus-lock@2.5.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0".
[17:31:16.250] warning "@chakra-ui/react > @chakra-ui/toast > @reach/alert > @reach/utils@0.13.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.8.0 || 17.x".
[17:31:16.250] warning "@chakra-ui/react > @chakra-ui/toast > @reach/alert > @reach/utils@0.13.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0 || 17.x".
[17:31:16.251] warning "@chakra-ui/react > @chakra-ui/toast > @reach/alert > @reach/visually-hidden@0.13.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.8.0 || 17.x".
[17:31:16.252] warning "@chakra-ui/react > @chakra-ui/toast > @reach/alert > @reach/visually-hidden@0.13.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0 || 17.x".
[17:31:16.252] warning "@chakra-ui/react > @chakra-ui/modal > @chakra-ui/focus-lock > react-focus-lock > react-clientside-effect@1.2.5" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0".
[17:31:16.252] warning "@emotion/react > @emotion/babel-plugin@11.9.2" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0".
[17:31:16.252] warning "@emotion/react > @emotion/babel-plugin > @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.16.7" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
[17:31:16.254] warning "react-pdf > file-loader@6.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
[17:31:16.257] warning "eslint-config-next > @typescript-eslint/parser > @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree > tsutils@3.21.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[17:31:21.993] [4/4] Building fresh packages...
[17:31:22.538] success Saved lockfile.
[17:31:22.545] Done in 29.87s.
[17:31:22.573] Detected Next.js version: 12.1.5
[17:31:22.578] Running "yarn run build"
[17:31:22.946] yarn run v1.22.17
[17:31:22.993] $ next build
[17:31:23.879] info  - Checking validity of types...
[17:31:26.071] 
[17:31:26.072] Failed to compile.
[17:31:26.072] 
[17:31:26.072] ./pages/contacts.js
[17:31:26.072] 121:43  Error: Do not pass children as props. Instead, nest children between the opening and closing tags.  react/no-children-prop
[17:31:26.073] 134:43  Error: Do not pass children as props. Instead, nest children between the opening and closing tags.  react/no-children-prop
[17:31:26.073] 
[17:31:26.073] info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
[17:31:26.091] error Command failed with exit code 1.
[17:31:26.091] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
[17:31:26.104] Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is failing linting.

In `pages/contact.js`, on lines 121 and 134 you probably have something that looks like

```
<SomeComponent children={<div>...</div>} />
```

Change that to,

```
<SomeComponent><div>...</div></SomeComponent>
```

per

```
[17:31:26.072] ./pages/contacts.js
[17:31:26.072] 121:43  Error: Do not pass children as props. Instead, nest children between the opening and closing tags.  react/no-children-prop
[17:31:26.073] 134:43  Error: Do not pass children as props. Instead, nest children between the opening and closing tags.  react/no-children-prop
```